# Black console screen shows up during boot (verbose mode not turned on)

Tags: startup, console, kernel-extensions

Over the past few months when my Mac boots up, the grey screen with the apple disappears and is replaced with a unix style console screen, which scrolls like a linux PC booting up.

I have tried reinstalling the OS (10.13.6) (and restoring my account from a Time Machine backup using the Migration Assistant) and booting in Safe Mode.

- Recovery Mode (Apple-R) - does not appear.
- Fresh install prior to Time Machine restore - did not appear.
- Normal boot after Time Machine restore - appears.
- Safe Mode boot (Shift key) after Time Machine restore - still appears.

Verbose mode is not turned on: `sudo nvram -p` does not show a `boot-args` parameter.

Hardware test (booting with D key) shows no issues.

My guess is there is perhaps some kernel driver or add-on that is doing this that was carried over from my time machine restore.  What is interesting is this continues even during a Safe Mode boot.

[image]

(apologies for the reflections on my screen when I took the image).

I'd like to know if it is possible to fix this without repeating a reformat and reinstall but with more selective Time Machine restores (using trial and error).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know this may sound silly because it seems like you have a grasp with unix and Macs so you've already done this. try a pram reset and smc reset. I'm thinking something in nvram is doing this right? Could be way off and I know PRAM is so overused for the wrong reasons.